# How to merge arrays inside array without removing duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($example as $ind => $v){
[0]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => b
    [value] => 12
    [kol] => jojo
)
[1]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => b
    [value] => 40
    [kol] => jojo
)
[2]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => b
    [value] => 9
    [kol] => jiji
)
[3]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => c
    [value] => 15
    [kol] => jaja
)
[4]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => c
    [value] => 30
    [kol] => jaja
)
}
```

I have to merge arrays inside an array without removing duplicates, the duplicates will only be removed on specifieds keys (in this example the key TYPE and ID). The TYPE and ID will be merged and the rest will only append in the array

Result desired:

```
[1]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => b
    [value] => 15
    [value] => 40
    [value] => 9
    [kol] => jojo
    [kol] => jojo
    [kol] => jiji
)
[2]
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => c
    [value] => 15
    [value] => 30
    [kol] => jaja
    [kol] => jaja
)
```

Any insight is helpful, thanks for your attention

Comment: You can't have __same keys__ in array.

Comment: you cant use/assing same key to create an array. This should be your array if you merge them`"id" => [ "0" => 1000 ], "type" => ["0" => 'b', "1" => 'c'],....`

Answer (score -1):

you cannot merge 2 arrays without losing same key values. In other words array key is unique for this array for that reason you can not

```
(
    [id] => 1000
    [type] => b
    [value] => 15
    [value] => 40
    [value] => 9
    [kol] => jojo
    [kol] => jojo
    [kol] => jiji
)
```

you can create array like this

```
(
    'id' => [1000,1000,...],
    'type' => ['a','b','c'],
    'value' => [15,30],
    'kol' => ['jaja','jaja'],
)
```

Comment: This is a description of a problem OP didnt know/see. This does not answer OPs question.

Comment: My dear it was just advice with some example, not answer)